# Sync both ways "camera picture folder" for android and pc

Tags: sync, gallery, dropbox

I am helping an older person who is not tech savvy enough to play with Android and USB cables and I'm tired of doing it for them.

They need open pictures taken with android smartphone (built in camera, saved to its local DCIM folder) onto their computer, edit them  (Windows) rotate, crop and so on, then transfer back to smartphone and then send via MMS. (yes, it's odd to use MMS i know, but as i said -we are talking about non tech savvy persons and they know how to operate mms so there is not possibility to switch them to using email).

Right now, i have use send anywhere to transfer picture to computer, wait for them to edit, and transfer back via send anywhere... or use usb cable.

I got idea to use dropbox, and dropbox let me send saved pictures directly to pc (via dropbox camera photo upload)  so this part is done, but it won't work other way (after editing file on dropbox photo folder -  it's not syncing back to phone) It's synced on dropbox folder via browser, but android app won't sync it back - i haven't seen that function < so it's useless.

Do You have any other idea of how can i sync pictures both way and make them after edit appear on built in android gallery so they just can select edited picture and send via mms?

Comment: If both PC and phone are connected to same (WiFi) network and it's possible to assign the phone a static IP, a FTP server would be the simplest approach in my opinion. Install some free app like MiXplorer which does have minimal FTP server built-in. It also provide a Quick Settings tile to turn the server on and off. On PC it would be just to copy and paste in a file explorer. A dynamic IP would take a little more hassle.

Comment: I like idea, thank You . I will explore it and share results.

Comment: rotation, cropping and filters can be applied using photos.googe.com. you can sync folder via photos app and access it via website and download it to local windows system. otherwise if you have dropbox synced then you can directly upload to images to photos.google.com and they will automatically show in your android photos app

Comment: google drive and google photos come to mind.  But dropbox should work, maybe it's a setting? :|

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SyncMe Wireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bv.wifisync&hl=en) application.

With SyncMe,you can copy, move, **sync** and backup your mp3, pictures and documents over WiFi (including Portable WiFi hotspot), (or cellular VPN)  to your computer. Nothing to be installed on your computer.

The application itself provides a step by step guide in setting up the folder to be synced (note: sharing must be enabled on your computer).

- Setup device folder to DCIM folder
- Setup computer folder to be the "shared folder" where photos are copied on the computer.
- Configure sync options and filters (and schedule-if needed.
- Tap the job to sync.

Basically the setup could be anything like this:

[image: IMG:]

*NB: No affiliation with the appplication but just use it as my daily driver for similar needs*

*Note: You may need to enable SMB1 on Windows*